# Why am I getting ANR in SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: java, android, timestamp, simpledateformat, android-anr-dialog

I am displaying notifications and notifications has timestamp. I am converting timestamp to date format using below code :

```
public static String getTimeFormat(Long unixSeconds, String pattern) {
    //Example EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy;
    Date date = new Date(unixSeconds);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    sdf.setTimeZone(timeZone);
    return sdf.format(date);
}
```

I am passing timestamp and pattern("MMM" or "dd" or "yyyy"). This method is called 100 times one for each notification to display time of notification as I am displaying 100 notifications. In Android, if the main thread(UI) of an Android app is blocked for too long, an "Application Not Responding" (ANR) error is triggered. I am getting error(ANR) at `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);`. Here is the error log :

```
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError: Application Not Responding
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: main
at java.lang.Object.internalClone(Native Method)
at java.lang.Object.clone(Object.java:241)
at java.text.Format.clone(Format.java:258)
at java.text.NumberFormat.clone(NumberFormat.java:599)
at java.text.DecimalFormat.clone(DecimalFormat.java:1095)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(SimpleDateFormat.java:695)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.&lt;init&gt;(SimpleDateFormat.java:623)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.&lt;init&gt;(SimpleDateFormat.java:598)
```

What is the issue?

Comment: execute on background thread

Comment: yea.. i can do that.. but what is the issue? i had similar problem with calender as well. check this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49526832/android-app-not-responding-at-calender-getinstance

Comment: when main thread is blocked you get this

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDateFormat is not a thread safe as per [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

> Date formats are not synchronized. It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally.

Remove **static** from `getTimeFormat(Long unixSeconds, String pattern)` and create a new object for each of the thread.

Comment: I am calling this in main thread(UI). And I am sure I am not calling this method from any other thread. So there shouldn't be any synchronization problem. Correct me if I am wrong.